# Parallel Uploads to S3 very slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having problem to figure out how to optimize the upload speed to Amazon S3 from within my C# application.

I create a loop to test 15 simultaneous uploads (running on the same image file).

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

for(int i=0; i<15; i++){

    AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey);
    TransferUtility tu = new TransferUtility(client);

    new Thread(() =>
     {
        // timer starts here
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
        tu.Upload(ur); // upload file synchronously 
       // timer stops here
     }
}
```

I have lots of free memory and CPU while running this loop was around 12%.

I put a timer to measure the time it takes for the upload to finish in each iteration in its own thread. The time was the same for each iteration, but the upload time was different.

15 images: avg 10 sec. uploads for each file

25 images: avg 35 sec. upload for each file

50 images: varies from 16 to 57 seconds for each file

I assumed that if each upload runs in parallel in each thread (which i have available), they all should run around 4 seconds approximately. From [this article](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/) I understand that parallelize the uploads is a good method to increase the upload throughput to S3 from my server.

What causes the upload to behave as such. I tested the code from my local computer running Windows 7, and testing it in IIS Express (saw the same results when testing on IIS8/WS 2012 EC2 instance, although speed was faster per upload, but same behavior).

I tried using the TransferUtility Async upload, but get the same behavior. I changed to async and used Thread in order to make this example easier to understand.

Goal: to make uploads to S3 in parallel. Thanks.

**Update:** I tried to use the `BeginUpload` async upload function and measured the time it takes to upload a **1.5KB** image to S3.

```
 new Thread(() =>
  {
    // stopWatch stopped at the FinishedAsyncUpload function
    tempObj.StopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    tempObj.StopWatch.Restart();

    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
    IAsyncResult ar =  tu.BeginUpload(ur, new AsyncCallback(FinishedAsyncUploadToTempFolder), tempObj);


                }).Start();
```

1 image upload:  avg 4 seconds.

5 concurrent image uploads: avg 5 seconds.

15 concurrent image uploads: 7 - 13 seconds

Comment: Your bandwidth is certainly a limiting factor, and parallelizing the uploads will *exacerbate* that factor. Presumably you have X bandwidth, and the image uploads are each taking a fraction of that value depending on the number of concurrent uploads.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it with 2KB images locally

Comment: Uploading a 1.5K image: 15 (5-7 sec), 30 (approx. 11 sec). Same results with very small images and I have a very fast Internet connection.

Comment: If you're uploading files in parallel it's not too surprising they will take longer to finish. But that's generally not the interesting factor anyhow - compare the total time to upload X pictures in k threads and check how those times change.